# MySQL - Criar tabela temporária de acordo com SELECT dinâmico

Tags: mysql, select, table

Existe alguma maneira de de criar uma tabela temporária de acordo com um select com colunas criadas dinamicamente, como mostra nos exemplos abaixo?

ex:

```
SELECT idCentroCusto, 'Dez/14', 'Jan/15', 'Fev/15', 'Mar/15', totalAnual
```

ou

```
SELECT idCentroCusto, 'Dez/14', 'Jan/15', 'Fev/15', 'Mar/15', 'Abr/15', 'Mai/15', totalAnual
```

Sendo que (como exibido acima) estes Meses/Ano são dinamicamente criados, de acordo com o parâmetro de calendário.

Comment: conseguiu criar o sql?

Answer (score 3):

Veja a documentação do [CREATE TABLE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html), pode ser criado através de uma consulta:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tabela_temporaria SELECT idCentroCusto, 'Dez/14', 'Jan/15', 'Fev/15', 'Mar/15', totalAnual;
```

Answer (score 0):

Tente utilizar o comando "CREATE TABLE AS" do MySQL

```
 CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table2 AS (SELECT idCentroCusto, 'Dez/14', 'Jan/15', 'Fev/15', 'Mar/15', 'Abr/15', 'Mai/15', totalAnual FROM table1)
```

Fonte:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5859391/create-a-temporary-table-in-a-select-statement-without-a-separate-create-table

Answer (score -1):

tabelas temporais são comuns no mysql,certifique-te primeiro q a tua versõa é supeiror a 3.23.
em seguida tens o comando:
create temporary table NomeTabelaTermporaria(
//corpo da tabela
.....
......
)

ou podes criar uma tabela temporária e clonar apartir de uma ja existente com seus dados
create temporary table novatabela select * from tabelaantiga;